# cf push failed due to java runtime version error

Tags: java, maven, cloud-foundry, sap-business-technology-platform

I'm trying to create a maven java project with spring boot and deploy it to SAP BTP.

the generated project from spring boot version is 3.2.1 and i have checked the java version is 17 as shown below.

[image]

**The issue :**
when i run ***cf push*** get the following error of java runtime mismatch version. it seems like it still using a java version 11 but i'm not sure from where

[image]

**the solution i have tried:**

- adding `JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE: '{jre: { version: 17.+ }}'` to env in manifest.yml file but not working too
  [image]

Comment: What is the output from `cf push`, in particular where the Java buildpack runs? That will show you what version of Java it installs, which as you say, looks like an older version. Also, confirm if the buildpack your using is an offline buildpack. If so, then what versions it includes can be limited.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SAPMachineJDK , pls set the env variables as below

env:

JBP_CONFIG_COMPONENTS: '{ "jres": ["com.sap.xs.java.buildpack.jdk.SAPMachineJDK"] }'
JBP_CONFIG_SAP_MACHINE_JDK: '{ "version": "17.+" }'

This is documented here -https://help.sap.com/docs/hana-cloud-database/sap-hana-cloud-sap-hana-database-developer-guide-for-cloud-foundry-multitarget-applications-sap-web-ide-full-stack/change-application-settings-for-cloud-foundry-java-run-time